# Disable Input based on Other Inputs Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to setup a knockout observable that will disable an input, if two other inputs are not both between 1 and 30.  Right now when I run the code in jsFiddle, my input is disabled.  Unfortunately, I am never able to reenable the input.  Here is the code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNv6n/)  Thanks for any help.

HTML

```
<!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your
UI -->
<p>Alcohol Days:
    <input data-bind="value: alcoholDays" />
</p>
<p>Alcohol 5+ Days:
    <input data-bind="value: alcoholFivePlusDays" />
</p>
<p>Alcohol 4- Days:
    <input data-bind="value: alcoholFourLessDays" />
</p>
<p>Drug Days:
    <input data-bind="value: drugDays" />
</p>
<p>Both Days:
    <input data-bind="value: bothDays, enable: enableBothDays" />
</p>
<p>Enable Both Days: <strong data-bind="text: enableBothDays"></strong>

</p>
<p>Alcohol Days: <strong data-bind="text: alcoholDays"></strong>

</p>
<p>Drug Days: <strong data-bind="text: drugDays"></strong>

</p>
<button data-bind="click: capitalizeLastName">Go caps</button>
```

javascript

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.alcoholDays = ko.observable("");
    self.alcoholFivePlusDays = ko.observable("");
    self.alcoholFourLessDays = ko.observable("");
    self.drugDays = ko.observable("");
    self.bothDays = ko.observable("");

    self.enableBothDays = ko.computed(function () {

        if ((parseInt(self.alcoholDays) > 0 && parseInt(self.alcoholDays) <= 30) && (parseInt(self.drugDays) > 0 && parseInt(self.drugDays) <= 30)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }, self);

}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Wade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hi check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarm/rJ6bS/)  **I fixed the problem** .

1.) cleared binding error in your fiddle

2.) re-structured computed observable

```
   self.enableBothDays = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        alert('In');
        var alcDays = Number(self.alcoholDays());
        var drgDays = Number(self.drugDays());
        alert(alcDays+','+drgDays);
        var temp = false;
  if (alcDays > 0 && alcDays <= 30 && drgDays > 0 && drgDays <= 30) {
        temp = true;
    } else {
        temp = false;
    }
        alert(temp);
        return temp;
}
});
```

3.) changed enable condition

[fiddle..](http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarm/rJ6bS/)

**mark it as answer**

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/SNv6n/20/

You were calling self.alcoholDays instead of self.alcoholDays().  If you add the parentheses to those calls in your computed and add in the function 'capitalizeLastName' it works.

```
self.capitalizeLastName = function () {
     alert('TODO');   
}
self.enableBothDays = ko.computed(function () {

    if ((parseInt(self.alcoholDays()) > 0 && parseInt(self.alcoholDays()) <= 30) && (parseInt(self.drugDays()) > 0 && parseInt(self.drugDays()) <= 30)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}, self);
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, unfortunately I could only accept one answer and went with who answered first.

Answer (score 0):

Use this
enable : enableBothDays()== true
Or
enable : enableBothDays== true